# How can I make a Google Sheet (or Excel) Gantt chart where some of the weekdays (not necessarily on the weekend) are not full workdays?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, gantt-chart

I'm trying to make a **dally** dynamic Gantt chart that takes into account that some of my workdays are not full workdays. For example, if Fridays and Saturdays are both half workdays and Sunday is a non-working day, a three full workdays task that starts on a Monday will be finished on Wednesday. But if the same task starts on a Friday, it will be finished on the consecutive Tuesday. So that the same three full workdays task can fill between three to five days on the Gantt chart.

1. How can I make this work dynamically on a Google Sheet (or Excel) Gantt chart? Can I make a function that receives the beginning date for a task, takes into accounts all my constraints (for example, Friday is a half-day), and calculates how many days should be filled in the Gantt chart?
2. Will it be possible to use a higher resolution like a subunit of 1/3 workday?

Attached:
[image: Example chart]

Comment: I added an example chart with the desired output manually written.

Comment: here is a blank sheet. paste your data/setup in there and Player0 (and I and others) can probably show you how to do it.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15SD3gsrERTK4LpkX7Z1sLGXvz4pus4X8QL7BivO2cb4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Strictly speaking, Sunday shouldn't be included in Task 4 (should it?) - the task only lasts one half-day after all and should be completed on Saturday. I was working on an alternative answer and found the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula i came up with that will give you cumulative "half-day"units starting at the start date and going up to the right.  That made it simple to create a conditional format to highlight those cells which fall within the project length.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B4="",,MMULT(N(VLOOKUP(TEXT(F$2:$2,"dddd"),'day guide'!B$3:D$9,3,0)*(F$2:$2>=B4)),N(F$2:$2>=TRANSPOSE(F$2:$2)))))
```

I will leave this sheet up indefinitely for others to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

### formula in F2:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(1*(F1&"1/2021")&":"&
 EOMONTH(1*(F1&"1/2021"), ))), {"d", "ddd"}), {2, 1})))
```

[image]

### formula in D4:

```
=QUERY(B4:B, "where B is not null format B 'dddd'")
```

[image]

### formmula in E4:

```
=INDEX(VALUE(F1&"1/2021")-1+TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(IF(QUERY({
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+0"),
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+Col2"),
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3"),
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4"),
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5"),
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6"), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select Col1+Col2+Col3+Col4+Col5+Col6+Col7"), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:8))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:9))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:10))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:11))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:12))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:13))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:14))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:15))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:16))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:17))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:18))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:19))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:20))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:21))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:22))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:23))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:24))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:25))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:26))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:27))), 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:28))), 
 IF(DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))>=29, 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:29))), 
 IFERROR(1/(0^ROW(INDIRECT("3:"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))))))), 
 IF(DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))>=30,  
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:30))), 
 IFERROR(1/(0^ROW(INDIRECT("3:"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))))))), 
 IF(DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))>=31, 
 QUERY(IF(N(IFNA(SPLIT(REPT(10, DAY(INDIRECT("B4:B"&MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))))-1), 0)*
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("1:"&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))))^0))=0)=0, 0, 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY({D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18; D12:D18}, 
 "limit "&DAY(EOMONTH(F1&"1/2021", 0))&" 
  offset "&MATCH(TEXT(F1&"1/2021", "dddd"), C12:C18, 0)-1))), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN("+", 1, "Col"&ROW(1:31))), 
 IFERROR(1/(0^ROW(INDIRECT("3:"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))))))}, 
 "offset 1 ", 0)>C4:C,,F2:AJ2))*1), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "max(Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("4:"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))))-ROW(A3)&")"))),, 2)
```

[image]

### custom formula for conditional formatting:

```
=($A4<>"")*(DAY($B4)<=(F$2*1))*(DAY($E4)>=(F$2*1))
```

[image]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lsnpdsk5pfMIbCo2Xg1yvuyU8FQHJBJcQ6_b_hBgQQg/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if you could avoid the use of a heavy array formula in doing this. Yes you can - the conditional format formula is still an array formula, but counts up increasing numbers of values naturally as you move across the range using a fairly simple sumproduct:

```
=and(F$2>=$B4,SUMPRODUCT(vlookup(text($F$2:F$2,"dddd"),indirect("'day guide'!$B$3:$D$9"),3,false)*($F$2:F$2>=$B4))<=$C4)
```

[image]

My end date formula uses two countifs to total up the whole days and half days but is just a pull-down formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(min(if((countifs(vlookup(text(F$2:AJ$2,"dddd"),'day guide'!$B$3:$D$9,3,false),1,column(F$2:AJ$2),"<="&column(F$2:AJ$2),F$2:AJ$2,">="&$B4)
+countifs(vlookup(text(F$2:AJ$2,"dddd"),'day guide'!$B$3:$D$9,3,false),2,column(F$2:AJ$2),"<="&column(F$2:AJ$2),F$2:AJ$2,">="&$B4)*2)>=C4,F$2:AJ$2,)))
```